# Making a function and sending it via message.channel.send

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to subtract the number sent in a message from 153

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

#the function
async def gamesAwayb1():
 return 153 - on_message() 
#not sure what to put instead of on_message

@bot.event

async def on_message(message):
  if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are" , gamesAwayb1() , "games away from Bronze 2")


  if 153 < int(message.content) < 200:
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 2")
```

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 13, in on_message
await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are" , gamesAwayb1(message) , "games away from Bronze 2")
TypeError: gamesAwayb1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can create a simple function,

```
def gamesAwayb1(num):
    return 153 - int(num) # to convert string to num
```

And pass the number from `message.content` when `on_message` is triggered like,
`gamesAwayb1(message.content)`.

Or you wouldn't need a function if you would just do something like,

```
async def on_message(message):
    if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
        await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(153 - int(message.content)))
```

If you want to check if valid number is in the input, you can try something like,

```
async def on_message(message):
    try:
        if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
            await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(153 - int(message.content)))
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send("Please enter valid number")
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I got a long error message
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 10, in on_message
    await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are" , 153 - int(message.content) , "games away from Bronze 2")

Comment: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 9, in on_message
    if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'you are in Bronze 2'
Ignoring exception in on_message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 10, in on_message
    await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are" , 153 - int(message.content) , "games away from Bronze 2")
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer and hopefully it should work!

Comment: tysm it works!  I hope you dont mind if I ask how it knows what {} is?

Comment: Oh nvm I looked it up.  Sry but I have one very last question.  How would I use the format so that it does the initial subtraction, does floor decision of that result and adds 1?

Comment: You can just do,  

`await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(floor(153 - int(message.content)) + 1))`  

It looks quite messy, so you can assign the variable for expression inside the format before the above statement and use that variable inside the format.

Comment: I went for the messy format and got a floor not defined

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to import it before using floor. Include this at the top `from math import floor`.

Comment: Sry if this is really obvious but how do I do the floor divide by 7?

Comment: For `floor division` you can just do like `46 // 7` , i.e 46 floor division 7.

Comment: Sry yes I know that but how do you floor divide the result of 157 - message.content in this situation and AFTER add 1

Comment: You can do this, `await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(((153 - int(message.content)) // 7) + 1))`